# Is there a simple and free hosting service for static websites?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I was using staticloud.com, but now the service seems to be shut down.

I'm looking for the simplest way to host a static site with some html, css and js files only.

What are my choices?

Comment: See [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20838/1253)

Comment: This is exactly what I find confusing. I only need a name of a recommended, simple, straightforward free service that can host a bunch of html based files like "staticloud" was.

Comment: Unfortunately that's off topic for this website

Comment: Eventually I found that using bitbucket.org + git for this purpose works well.

Comment: also you can use Github pages or Amazon S3.

Comment: As this comes up in Google: I suggest http://www.ziphaze.com. It supports custom domains and drag/drop uploads of a zip. Although I'm being slightly biased, because I created it.

Comment: Google Drive has an option to host sites for free.